# React.js routing problem when define route

Tags: reactjs

1. My routing works if I define my route as below, that means I can access my component - MatchingReport in *http://localhost:3000/Home/CS5487/1234567*

```
    class App extends Component {
      
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)   
      }

      render(){
        return (
          <div>
            <Router>
              <Switch>
                <Redirect exact from="/" to="/login" />
                <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
                <Fragment>
                  <AppBar title="Plagiarism Detection System"/>
                    <Route exact path="/Home" component={TaskLists} />
                    <Route exact path="/Home/:id" component={Submissions} />
                    <Route exact path="/Home/:id/:student" component={MatchingReport} /> //can access this page
                </Fragment>
              </Switch>
            </Router>
          </div>
        )
      }  
    }
```

2. However, if I define my routes in another file: routes.js and loop through the routes in App.js, I will get the following error:

```
    Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
    1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
    2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
    3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
    See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    ▶ 4 stack frames were collapsed.
    MatchingReport
    C:/visal/plagiarism-detection-system/frontend/src/view/MatchReport/index.js:19
      16 | 
      17 | export default function MatchingReport(props){
      18 |     
    > 19 |     const classes = useStyles();
      20 | 
      21 |     return(
      22 |         <Box className="whole-container">
    View compiled
    (anonymous function)
    C:/visal/plagiarism-detection-system/modules/Route.js:55
      52 | }
      53 | 
      54 | return (
    > 55 |   <RouterContext.Provider value={props}>
         | ^  56 |     {props.match
      57 |       ? children
      58 |         ? typeof children === "function"
    View compiled
    ▶ 18 stack frames were collapsed.
```

3. Below is my implementation for routes.js and app.js.

// routes.js

```
import { Login, TaskLists, Submissions, MatchingReport } from "./view/export";

export default [
    { 
        path: "/login", 
        name: "Login", 
        Component: Login 
    },
    { 
        path: "/Home", 
        name: "Home Page", 
        Component: TaskLists 
    },
    { 
        path: "/Home/:id", 
        name: "Submissions", 
        Component: Submissions 
    },
    { 
        path: "/Home/:task/:student", 
        name: "MatchingReport", 
        Component: MatchingReport 
    }
]
```

// App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)   
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Redirect exact from="/" to="/login" />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Fragment>
              <AppBar title="Plagiarism Detection System"/>
                {routes.map(({ path, Component }, key) => (
                  <Route exact path={path} render={Component} /> 
              ))}
            </Fragment>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    )
  }  
}
```

4. MatchingReport implementation:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import sample2 from '../../resources/sample2.png'; // Tell webpack this JS file uses this image
import sample3 from '../../resources/sample3.jpeg'; // Tell webpack this JS file uses this image
import { Container, Grid, Box, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import DynamicBox from '../../components/DynamicBox';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Image from 'material-ui-image';
import '../../styles/media.scss';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    textAlign: 'left',
  },
}));

export default function MatchingReport(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Box className='whole-container'>
      <Container className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container spacing={3}>
          <Grid item xs={7} spacing={2}>
            <Image src={sample3} />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={5}>
            <DynamicBox />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: Only significant difference I can see between the two implementations is switching from the `Route` component's `component` prop to the `render` prop.

Comment: Owh, thanks I see the problem now

Comment: Was that the issue?

Comment: Yes, it works fine after changing to using the component props. But one thing that bothers me is that using the render prop I can access the second component http://localhost:3000/Home/CS5487/ but got the above error only when I try to access the third component - http://localhost:3000/Home/CS5487/1234567. I am quite new to React and am still looking into React router props  implementation.

Comment: I suspect something is throwing an error and it's manifesting as an invalid hook use. Can you share that `MatchingReport` component code in your question? You may need to do some debug sleuthing in that component. Comment out all the code and render something simple, and then slowly/incrementally uncomment a small chunk of code at-a-time until it breaks with the error. This should help you narrow down the cause.

Comment: @DrewReese, shared the MatchingReport component, kindly please help to point out any problems with my implementation.

Comment: Nothing overt jumps out at me as an issue. And you've no issue rendering `MatchingReport` with the old `<Route exact path="/Home/:id/:student" component={MatchingReport} />` implementation?

Comment: @Boey Try to specify the unique `key` attribute for your `Route` items: `<Route exact key={key} path={path} render={Component} />`